# Hyphenation without hyphen symbol in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I would like to be able to separate a formula in math mode without a hyphen-symbol "-" appearing. I know w/o math mode it works with "".

**Example**
Take this formula:

```
$Algorithms = (Generate, Add, Delete, Setup, Calculate)$
```

With hyphen it's no problem:

```
$Algorithms\- = (Generate,\- Add,\- Delete,\- Setup,\- Calculate)$
```

But this will not work:

```
$Algorithms"" = (Generate,"" Add,"" Delete,"" Setup,"" Calculate)$
```

Instead it displays the ""

[image]

I appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use words in math mode without wrapping them in `\mathrm` or similar command.

If you want to allow a line break after commas, use

```
,\linebreak[0]
```

By the way, `""` is a shorthand in `babel-german` or other languages, but its purpose is not what you claim and, as you discovered, it doesn't work in math mode.

Anyway, such a long formula is better typeset in a display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some words to see what happens
$\mathrm{Algorithms} = (\mathrm{Generate}, \mathrm{Add},
  \mathrm{Delete},\linebreak[0] \mathrm{Setup},\linebreak[0] \mathrm{Calculate})$ and other words
$\mathrm{Algorithms} = (\mathrm{Generate}, \mathrm{Add},
  \mathrm{Delete}, \mathrm{Setup},\linebreak[0] \mathrm{Calculate})$ and other words

But it's better in a display
\[
\mathrm{Algorithms} = (\mathrm{Generate}, \mathrm{Add},
  \mathrm{Delete}, \mathrm{Setup}, \mathrm{Calculate})
\]
so no splitting problem appears.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! sometimes I have to list the algorithms in plain text, I can't do it in display mode. And I use \mathsf{} for each word.